# Machine Learning Algorithm

Tags: ros, leg-detector, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

Would it be possible to know which **Machine Learning Algorithm** was used to find leg patterns in the returned laser scans reading in the **leg_detector** ROS package (http://wiki.ros.org/leg_detector) ?

Greetings,

Ilyass

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283913/machine-learning-algorithm/) by [itaouil](https://answers.ros.org/users/33911/itaouil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2018-02-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on 2018-02-28**:
Do you mean http://wiki.ros.org/skeleton_markers?

As far as i know , machine learning is not used . Robotics still works on deterministic classical approach .

**Comment by [itaouil](https://answers.ros.org/users/33911/itaouil/) on 2018-02-28**:
Hey Chriss,

I updated my question. I meant the following package http://wiki.ros.org/leg_detector :)

**Comment by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on 2018-02-28**:
https://github.com/wg-perception/people/blob/indigo-devel/leg_detector/src/leg_detector.cpp

This is the source code pertaining to the leg_detector .

I am not sure exactly what algorithm they are using in this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is an implementation of [this paper](http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/%7Earras/papers/arrasICRA07.pdf)

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2018-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [itaouil](https://answers.ros.org/users/33911/itaouil/) on 2018-02-28**:
Thank you!